# Extracting the Percentage of color (Red,blue,green,yellow,orange) in an image in Opencv?

Tags: opencv, colors, hsv

I have to differentiate between 5 types of images which could have mostly either red,green, blue, orange or yellow color with some white or black color. I have to find which color is prominent in the image.

The source of images is Webcam, so the actual color also depends upon the illumination and distance of the image from webcam. An example of my image can be seen here:

http://ian-albert.com/hazmat_placards/placard-2-flammable-gas.png

I am trying to calculate the percentage based upon "Hue" values. I am specifying some range for each color. My ranges are:

**Red:** 0-10
**Green:** 50-65

**Yellow:** 18-21

**Blue:** 100-115

**PROBLEM:** Even though the image displayed is not Red still i am getting high % for red color.

My code is following:

```
int findRect::checkByHSV(int svmResult, Mat detectedSquare)
{

    Mat hsv_img;
    cvtColor(detectedSquare,hsv_img,CV_BGR2HSV);

    Vec3b pixel;
    float totalPixel=0; // to count the total number of pixels in an image---to get the Percentage later
    float totalClass[6];// because we want to test for 5 classes+ a garbage class.{{ Class-0 -> Garbage, Class-1->Orange, Class-2->Green, Class-3->Red, 
                        //  Class-4->Blue, Class-5->Yellow }} 

    for(int i=0; i<hsv_img.rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<hsv_img.cols; j++)
        {

            totalPixel++;
            pixel= hsv_img.at<Vec3b>(i,j);

            if(  pixel[0]>0 &&  pixel[0]<1  )           totalClass[1]++;    // Class-1->Orange
            else if (  pixel[0]>50 &&  pixel[0]<65  )   totalClass[2]++;    // To check Green class-2 //svmResult==2 && 
            else if (  pixel[0]>0 &&  pixel[0]<10  )        totalClass[3]++;    // Class-3->Red
            else if (  pixel[0]>100 &&  pixel[0]<115  )     totalClass[4]++;    // Class-4->Blue
            else if (  pixel[0]>18 &&  pixel[0]<21  )       totalClass[5]++;    // Class-5->Yellow
        }

    }

    float percentage[5];
    totalClass[0]=0; //Putting zero to the Garbage class

    for (int i=0; i<=5; i++)
    {
        percentage[i] = (totalClass[i] / totalPixel )*100;
    }

    cout<<"\n Organge: "<<percentage[1]<<"  Green: "<<percentage[2]<<"  Red: "<<percentage[3]<<"  Blue: "<<percentage[4]<<"  Yellow: "<<percentage[5]<<"\n \n";

    return svmResult;
}
```

Comment: What color is the image?
Also, the OpenCV hue spectrum wraps around. Red will be 0-10 and 170-180

Comment: @Osiris: As i have already mentioned, the image can consist of mainly Red, Green, Orange, Blue or yellow color...with some black or white color.

Comment: No, I meant this particular image. You're saying the image displayed is not Red. What output are you expecting? Maybe you can include the image in the post.

Comment: I am unable to embed image here at SO. I meant that any image which is not red i.e. mostly green,blue or yellow. And the problem is, i am getting high % of red for such images.

Comment: And major problem is coming for yellow image...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned that you can have some White and/or some Black.

HSV allows you to have any value for the H component and:

1. A High V, Low S gives White
2. A Low V gives black

In other words: White and Black can give you Red OR Green OR Orange OR ... etc if you only judge by the H component.

Personally I'd say stick to RGB (or BGR whatever), or compensate for the fact the S and V can affect the colour.

Comment: But i think that in RGB there would be so many combinations to extract a particular color but in HSV i can extract the color directly from HUE component. White and Black component in all the images are more or less same. The images are different due to their main color which could be red,green,orange,blue or yellow

Comment: Green => Little Red, Little Blue, Mostly Green.
Blue  => Little Red, Mostly Blue, Little Green.
Red   => Mostly Red, Little Blue, Little Green.
Orange=> Mostly Red, Little Blue, Half   Green.
Yellow=> Mostly Red, Little Blue, Mostly Green.

[Source](http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3116/3103830956_bbe3c4b21f_o.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function countNonZero and divide by the total number of pixels of image. A example of use:

```
vector<Mat> channels;
split(hsv_img,channels);

Mat red, blue, green;
inRange(channels[0], Scalar(0), Scalar(10), red); // red
// ... do the same for blue, green, etc only changing the Scalar values

double image_size = hsv_img.cols*hsv_img.rows;
double red_percent = ((double) cv::countNonZero(red))/image_size;
```

But it could be not optimal depending of the application (for example, if you need to scan lots of image). Anyway, you can use it to compare the values.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your answer seems to structured but i am also doing the same by using other code. Actually, the input images keep changing on and illumination could also vary.

Comment: It would not be a problem, it is only a matter of reloading the image and using the code again. About the changes in illumination, you can equalize the histogram before doing the operations.
EDIT: I did not see the webcam you mentioned in the question. I think that is possible to run the code in realtime. Try to test and see if it works.

Comment: As i am not getting desired results so i think that it would be better to do histogram matching.

Comment: Now, i want to create the histogram of both the images (input image and a sample image). As, both the images have almost similar size so, i dont want to slide one over another to calculate histogram over certain window....can you tell me how can i do it?

Comment: You could ask as a new question your comment. I'm not sure if I understood the slide part, but to compare/match histograms, take a look at this tutorial: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_comparison/histogram_comparison.html

Comment: ok i will start a new question. Actually i don't need a very complicated histogram matching as i am using histogram matching only as a cross checking tool before declaring my final result.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that black or white have Hue=0 (which is red). But in this case the saturation is very low. What you can do is multiply each pixel by its saturation somewhere.

For example:

- Using thresholds and AND operations, create a binary image with the "red" pixels in white and all non-red pixels in black.
- Multiply this image by the saturation. Now you will have a grayscale image that says how red each pixel is.
- You can threshold this second image if you need a binary image

Pure black is counted as red (HUE=0), but you will have the same problem with bluish black (a very dark blue). So the previous procedure should be repeated for all colors you want to detect.